# Multidimensional Array: Extract second value if first is present

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array:

```
array(3) {
  ["checkIn"]=>  array(0) {}
  ["code"]=> array(0) {}
  [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["checkIn"]=> string(10) "2021-02-02"
        ["code"]=>string(10) "00Q4K00"
      }
}
```

which I initialize in this way:

```
$array= array(
    'checkIn'=>array(),
    'code'=>array()
    );
```

and so I value:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $array[] = array('checkIn'=>$row['checkIn'], 'code'=>$row['code']);
  }
```

I can't figure out how to extract 'code' if '2021-02-02' is present:

```
if ( in_array('2021-02-02', array_column($array, 'checkIn')) ){
   echo code??
}
```

Comment: well for a start that data is in `$array[0]` not `$array`

Comment: You could make your own life easier (perhaps) if you can indicate where the array formatting comes from. Why exactly are there identical keys in the outer array (with no values) as in the inner (which does have values)?

Comment: Its now not clear is you actually want to load the data from the database into the currently unused `'checkIn'=>array(),` and `'code'=>array()` or you are happy with the `[0]` numeric occurance. Need to sort that out before proceeding. Also would it not be easier to craft the query to do this rather than load data and then work out if its what you wanted to see

Comment: If you remove the way you 'initialize' your data, you can interact with the keys directly. I think this would be easier and cleaner to initialize it as `$array = array();` only